# GRPC server streaming call- keep response streams and write to from another method in server side

Tags: c#, grpc

I develop a grpc server that keeps response streams of different clients,
in order to write them responses from another method later, based on an event that will occur.
But when the event occurs I try to write to the kept response streams but get an ex: {"Can't write the message because the request is complete."}
where and why is it completed? any solution to enable writing to response streams at a later time?

this is the client code:

```
static async Task Main(string\[\] args)

{

        var userId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:8080");

        Job.JobClient client;

        client = new Job.JobClient(channel);
        
        using var jobServerStreaming = client.GetJobsRT(new JobsRequest() { UserId = userId });
        try
        {                
            var readerTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await foreach (var res in jobServerStreaming.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"jobServerStreaming Response: {res.Message}");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

}

server code:

```
public class JobService : Job.JobBase

{

public static Dictionary\<string, IServerStreamWriter\<JobsReply\>\>      \_grpcResponseStreams = new();

    //Server streaming
    public override async Task GetJobsRT(
        JobsRequest request,
        IServerStreamWriter<JobsReply> responseStream,
        ServerCallContext context)
    {
        _grpcResponseStreams.Add(request.UserId, responseStream);

        await responseStream.WriteAsync(new JobsReply() { Message = $"Let you know jobs updates and         executions on real-time." });
    }
```

}

in the server code there is a method that called after a message from other server is coming and then it try to write updates to the response streams

```
async ValueTask AfterMessageReceived(Message context)
        try
        {
            foreach (var responseStream in JobService._grpcResponseStreams.Values)
                await responseStream.WriteAsync(new JobsReply() { Message = context.Message});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)//** -> here the ex is thrown {"Can't write the message because the request     is complete."}**
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you exit the server method GetJobsRT you complete the call. You need to not exit the method until you have finished with the response stream.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing in your code is sent one message via a gRPC stream from server to the client, then complete the call. There is no reason for the stream to still exist, you send one message in the `GetJobsRT` method, then the method ends and the stream as well, only the gRPC channel continues to exist. If you want to change that behavior, you should be aware of two things:

---

**1. You should not exit the server-side streaming method.**

Simple example on how to change your method with a loop to keep the stream alive:

```cs
//Server streaming
public override async Task GetJobsRT(
JobsRequest request,
IServerStreamWriter<JobsReply> responseStream,
ServerCallContext context)
{
    _grpcResponseStreams.Add(request.UserId, responseStream);

    // stay in this loop for as long as you want the stream to exist
    while(!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && streamToClientShouldExist) 
    {
        // check if you want to send messages, your implementation here in the next lines

        // then wait a bit
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Since writing the messages into the gRPC stream is triggered somewhere else in your use case, one solution could be to implement the [observer pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern). I already did this once for a gRPC stream a while ago, and can verify that it works. Basically you stay inside the function and observe for an incoming message that you want to sent via the stream, and when the message comes you write it into the stream. Simplified code:

```cs
//Server streaming
public override async Task GetJobsRT(
JobsRequest request,
IServerStreamWriter<JobsReply> responseStream,
ServerCallContext context)
{
    _grpcResponseStreams.Add(request.UserId, responseStream);

    try
    {
        // stay in this loop for as long as you want the stream to exist
        while(!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && streamToClientShouldExist) 
        {
            // check if a message queue in the observer has any messages 
            // that should be sent to the client
            while (observer.MessageQueue.Any())
            {
                // dequeue messages and sent them until all messages are sent
            }

            // then wait a bit
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // client has unsubscribed, in case you need to do sth here
    }
    finally
    {
        // final clean up
    }
}
```

In addition you could implement [Keep-Alive pings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#keep-alive-pings) to make sure that the stream stays alive and does not get cancelled early.

---

**2. Keep in mind that gRPC services are [registered as transient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/clientfactory?view=aspnetcore-6.0#register-grpc-clients) if registered the default way.**

This means that a new instance of your `JobService` class is created whenever a client requests a gRPC stream from your server for this service, and that instance gets cleaned up when the client connection ends. I noticed you already made `_grpcResponseStreams` static and added a specific user id for each stream to identify them unambiguously, otherwise it would currently only exist during the `GetJobsRT` method lifetime, so you probably know, but I thought I mention this specifically because this might be another hurdle when implementing concurrent streams for the same gRPC service.